# Cannot open rstudio from command line though installation worked

Tags: r, installation, rstudio, conda

I can't start `rstudio` from my linux terminal. It always shows me this message:

```
Unable to determine real path of R script /home/remi/anaconda3/bin/R (system error 2 (No such file or directory))
```

I have Kubuntu 18 and anaconda installed on it.

I had trouble with installing curl and other libraries that need curl.

Since it was maybe due to a problem of paths, I removed R and RStudio from my conda environment in order to work only on the R and RStudio installed in Kubuntu. Something must have gone wrong.

I have tried to remove and reinstall both R and RStudio but it didn't work.

Weirdly, I can launch RStudio from my application launcher and I was able to install all the libraries I needed.

I would like to be able to launch RStudio from the terminal without any problem.

Does someone know what the problem is ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you start R from command line? If so find the directory where  R is located (`which R`) , then check that  rstudio is also located in that directory  . Then find where the system is looking for Rstudio (  `which rstudio`  )  . Post the outputs here, or if you know how to symlink, can just make one `rstudio`  point to other

Comment: I can start R from command line. When I check their location, R and RStudio are both in /usr/bin/. I know how to do a symlink but between rstudio and what ? Thanks

Comment: Make the rstudio (as shown by `which rstudio`) point to real location of Rsutio. You can get the real location by launching Rstudio from menu, finding its PID with `ls -e| egrep rstudio` and then finding its path with `sudo ls -l /proc/12345/exe` where 12345 is the  PID or rstudio

Comment: I actually used `ps -aux | grep rstudio` to find the real location of `rstudio` but the symlink worked. Thanks a lot !

Comment: nice to know it helped. ps -aux output can be a handful . And I actually meant `ps`, and not ls :-)